# Smaller PanoramaItems in a Windows Phone 7 app

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to decrease the default width of a Panorama control's PanoramaItems?

They can be made wider by specifying `Orientation="Horizontal"` and a width larger than 432. However, specifying a width less than 432 does not result in a smaller PanoramaItem. It's minimum width is 432 always.

I played around with the templates but couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't anything you can do about that.  The Panorama has the width of its items baked in as 48 pixels less that its own width.

Comment: This is likely a deliberate design choice consistent with suggestions throughout CTP and Beta by the design and product teams that reserving these small areas of display from the "next" screen is the visual cue to guide users to explore in that direction with swipe gestures. On the home page it sounds like you're looking to recreate in some form this is also evident.

Answer (score 2):

PanoramaItems are not designed to have a smaller width. If you wanted to do this you'd probably need to create your own version of the Panorama control.

**Don't do this though!**

Not only would it be a lot of effort to get right you'd break user expectations about how the panorama would work.

- Would/could you allow multiple items to be displayed at once?
- What would be the impact on navigation?
- How would you communicate to users that your app works slightly differently to all the other ones on the phone?
- How would you justify the mental cost to the user of the different behaviour?
- What would the impact be on the item headers if they were smaller?

With the PanoramaItem width set to at least (almost) the width of the screen it allows the user to see and focus on a single item at a time.

Also, potentially having fewer items on screen at once can also help with performance too.